# write a foreach loop from a for loop

Tags: php, foreach

I want to convert my for loop to a foreach loop but i am confused.I always write wrong code .

my for loop

```
$cd = $c->Select();
if($cd>0)
{
    $sl=1;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($cd); $i++)
    {
        print '<td>'.$sl++.'</td>';
        print '<td>'.$cd[$i][1].'</td>';
        print '<td>'.$cd[$i][2].'</td>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your attempt at the `foreach` loop?  You'll be more likely to get a good answer more quickly if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($cd as $item)
{
  print '<td>'.$sl++.'</td>';
  print '<td>'.$item[1].'</td>';
  print '<td>'.$item[2].'</td>';
}
```

[**Example**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/19bb79bfa2651174f4fc84130e2b342135f2aaff)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop in your `$cd` array as follow

```
$sl = 1;
foreach($cd as $data)
{
    print '<td>'.$sl++.'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$data[1].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$data[2].'</td>';
}
```